# How do I know the direction of the Bootstrap carousel slide? Any event?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, slide, direction

I need to bind an event upon bootstrap carousel slide to right only. I've got this code:

```
$('#carousel-showcase').bind('slid', function () {
    $("#wrap").animate({
        backgroundPositionX: '+=50%'
    },0);
});
```

But it works doesn't matter the direction. Any help?

Comment: please include the version of bootstrap you are using.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Bootstrap 3, you can get the direction from the slide event:

```
$('#carousel-showcase').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (event) {
    console.log(event.direction);
});
```

Keep in mind that this is only for the slide event, not slid.

Comment: thanks, this seems to be the shortest way. sorry, im an amateur programmer, can you advice me how to use console.log(event.direction); in my code? thanks in advance

Comment: @YevgenySimzikov use alert(event.direction); if that helps.  What you will want to do is make an if statement to only run code if the event.direction indicates the slide is going right.

Comment: The browser console can be accessed by right clicking a web page, selecting inspect element, then select the console tab. Any data passed to the function console.log will be printed here. Take a look at the console in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/pU7Fb/15/) and you should see text printed everytime the slide and slid events are fired.

Comment: @YevgenySimzikov please accept this answer if you are satisfied, thanks!